# Cannot set padding bigger than 100px in Codename One designer

Tags: codenameone

Codename One UI Builder does not allow to set padding to value bigger than 100px. In my particular case I need padding to be set to 140px. How can I achieve this?

**Rephrased question:**

See screenshots below. First one is for iPad, second - for iPhone.

[image]
[image]

On tablets and on the phone width should be calculated as minimum of 528px and portrait width  minus left and right paddings (20px each).

LWUIT is far not the same as, for example, JavaFX and building of pages is way more complicated, mostly because layout managers are not taking into consideration preferred dimensions. And width cannot be set directly. Setting of preferred size is deprecated and not working actually. Technically I can implement my own Layout, which I already did once in Codename One and is not a problem at all. But I would rather avoid writing my own layout unless no other way is available.

Comment: Which component are you referring to? The button? The text field? Are the provided screenshots of what you have or what you are trying to achieve? Setting padding or specifying sizes in pixels is completely wrong because of the DPI differences. Layouts treat preferred size differently, setting it is always a mistake when you have MANY DPI's to support.

Comment: Hi I highlighted containers I was talking about. Screenshots provided are something I want to achieve. What would you recommend as an alternative in this case? TableLayout and percents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We blocked this since it seems like you are practically setting things in an absolute position and that is probably a bad idea. You can use millimeters to work around this since those are usually much larger than pixels but either way you should seriously rethink what you are doing if you need so many pixels.

You are thinking about this wrong. On a retina ipad mini 140 pixels will be exactly HALF of what they would be on an iPad. Same goes to an iPhone 6+ vs. iPhone 4. You need to discard the concept of pixels entirely and think in millimeters in which case 100mm is way more than enough. Furthermore your iPad design looks like a blown up iPhone design which is generally not the best practice, you would want to make more productive use of available space.

You can create a custom iPad design by using the override feature which allows you to do something different for tablet/phone.

Notice that JavaFX/AWT/Swing ignore the problems of DPI variance at this scale so they don't incorporate those complexities and won't fit in devices that have such a wide difference in DPI.

Comment: Yes, I am setting paddings rather as a workaround. Could you check paraphrased question, please?

Comment: See my revised answer

Comment: If you type into google images search something like 'ipad login' you will login pages and they all are centred and have fixed size. How can I set width of container, say, to 100mm without creating custom layout?

Comment: Centering something has nothing to do with padding and shouldn't be accomplished via padding. You can place the entire UI in the center of a border layout and indicate that it should use "absolute center" mode which will center the entire UI without padding. This will also work correctly when the device is flipped or in multitasking mode if the UI is resized.

Comment: Thanks. I completely agree that paddings are not way to go and paraphrased question is not mentioning using paddings for resolving this problem. However, 'absolute centre' option is DEPRECATED (why?) in cn1 API. But let's imagine I use BorderLayout with absoluteCentre option. Then how BorderLayout calculates width of form container?

Comment: The deprecation comment points that the API now uses a constant by the same name and the center behavior method. The layout manager does that dynamically, recursively. You can see our developer guide where we actually explain how to write a layout manager.